# react-spline bug, after built react project, the spline content is gone. in spline frame responsive

Tags: reactjs, build, responsive, spline

i have some issu with react-splie after build. my spline content is gone after built with react, but when resize the window, the content is coming back again. my setting in spline is frame size 'responsive'. anybody have same issue like me? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a camera object added and use it, this worked for me. If it doesn't work, save your file and start a new document, and make sure your camera is one of the first things you set up. Good luck!